# get row in mysql using data from friendly url and using regular expression

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I need to write code for getting data from a database by a friendly url.

I have a table `company` with the field `title` for storing some info about a company. I want to get data by title using friendly url. E.g. `example.com/company/aurum-1`. First I tried to change some defined symbols to `-` :

```
function seoUrl2CompanyName($string) {
    $string = preg_replace("/[-ecsui]/","%",$string);
    return $string."%";
}
```

`[-ecsui]` is used because my native language has non-standard symbols like šįėęų which I cant use in my friendly url, so I tried to change them to `%` and use the following mysql to find the company by title:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM company
       "WHERE title LIKE '".seoUrl2CompanyName($_GET['company'])."';
```

But if I use this logic I meet with some difficulties when select return more than one row. E.g

> example.com/company/aurum -> seoUrl2CompanyName('aurum')-> a%r%m% ->
>   like  a%r%m% -> 24 rows in my table for match this pattern

My goal is to create the fastest way to find the company from company table by name using data from url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take the suggest from @AgeDeO but expand your SQL like this, that you take the data the company-name reflects AND the ID you get from your URL:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * 
        FROM company
        WHERE title LIKE '".seoUrl2CompanyName($_GET['company'])."'
        AND ID = ".$myId.";
```

With these 2 factors, you should only get one row and can be sure, that no one just replace his 1 with a 2 and gets other companys data.

Comment: I agree that this is a better solution then mine, but it does not ensure that you won't get other companies data. It it still guessable and because you are using `like` guessing can be quite easy

Answer (score 1):

NEVER EVER DO THIS:

> I want get data by title

What are you going to do when the company name changes? What when two companies have the same name? What happens with spaces, special characters etc...

I understand that you want friendly urls and that is possible, just add the company name as dummy data in the url. Show the company name but do not use it.

Use `example.com/1/company/aurum-1` instead, where the `1` is the actual company id.

Beware that it is fairly easy to guess other companies like this. When I change the `1` in a `2` I could have access to the other company like this. If you do not want this, make sure you check for permissions on page load.